# Having Trouble Deserializing A Message

Tags: xml, soap, nested, deserialization

I am having a little trouble deserializing the following XML.  I can get the orders populated fine but the nested packages are givng me a bit of a tough time.  The message being a soap message is cleaned prior to serialization. I think the issue is with the XSI attributes in the package tags?

Please note: The following XML is from a SOAP messge, it is returned from the getSoapBody(string) function.  All other (40 or so) soap responses are fine, its just the double nested suff I am having problems with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">12345</OrderNumber>
    <Promotion xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <Agent_Contact xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <Packages>
        <Package>
          <OrderPackageType_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</OrderPackageType_ID>
          <Title_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Title_ID>
          <StartIssue xsi:type="xsd:string">November 2010</StartIssue>
          <EndIssue xsi:type="xsd:string" />
        </Package>
        <Package>
          <OrderPackageType_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</OrderPackageType_ID>
          <Title_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Title_ID>
          <StartIssue xsi:type="xsd:string">October 2010</StartIssue>
          <EndIssue xsi:type="xsd:string" />
         </Package>
      </Packages>      
    </Order>
    <Order> .... </Order>
</Orders>
```

The code which deseiralizes is as follows

```
        NameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

        'Initialize our parser context for the xsi namespace
        Context = New XmlParserContext(Nothing, NameSpaceManager, Nothing, XmlSpace.None)

        'Set up our reader settings
        ReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
        ReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment

        'getSoapBody(Response) rips out the env stuff and sets up for serialization this works
        'fine and I can populate all other SOAP messages fine. It just returns elements inside 
        'the SOAP response body
        Reader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(GetSoapBody(Response)), ReaderSettings, Context)

        If Deserializer.CanDeserialize(Reader) Then
            'Deserialize here
            ResponseObject = CType(Deserializer.Deserialize(Reader), U)
        Else
            Throw New SerializationException("Unable to deserialize class object")
        End If
```

Orders populates fine into my orders class, packages returns nothing?
I am using a list of package in the order class.

```
''' <remarks/>
<Serializable()> _
<XmlType("Order", AnonymousType:=True, NameSpace:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
Public Class Order
     'other memebers first
       .....
      'nested packed class declaration
       <XmlElement("Package", NameSpace:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
       Public Property Packages() As List(Of Package)
          Get
            If _Packages Is Nothing Then
               _Packages = New List(Of Package)
            End If
            Return _Packages
           End Get
           Set(ByVal value As List(Of Package))
             _Packages = value
           End Set
       End Property
End Class
```

My package class is decorated in the following way.

```
<Serializable()> _
<XmlType("Package", AnonymousType:=True, NameSpace:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"> _
 Public Class Package 
         <XmlElementAttribute("OrderPackageType_ID", Form:=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable:=True)> _
        Public Property OrderPackageType_ID() As NullableInt
          Get
            Return _OrderPackageType_ID
          End Get
          Set(ByVal value As NullableInt)
            _OrderPackageType_ID = value
          End Set
       End Property
        ....
 End Class
```

The packages class populates fine with the following XML. But as a nested element, like above, it returns empty?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Packages>
        <Package>
          <OrderPackageType_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</OrderPackageType_ID>
          <Title_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Title_ID>
          <StartIssue xsi:type="xsd:string">November 2010</StartIssue>
          <EndIssue xsi:type="xsd:string" />
        </Package>
        <Package>
          <OrderPackageType_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</OrderPackageType_ID>
          <Title_ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Title_ID>
          <StartIssue xsi:type="xsd:string">October 2010</StartIssue>
          <EndIssue xsi:type="xsd:string" />
         </Package>
     </Packages>
```

Any help would be appreciated, hope I have supplied enough information for you.

regards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had better answer this, I found the answer a while ago now. I needed to decorate the properties and class correctly similar to the following.  this solved my issue.

```
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Package", GetType(Package), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable:=True)> _
    Public Property Packages() As Package()
        Get
            Return _Packages
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Package())
            _Packages = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Package")> _
Public Class Package
....
End Class
```